# How to configure WiFi/network settings?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, configuration, wicd

I changed from Windows 10 to Ubuntu a few days ago and the WiFi won’t work on my notebook. It only works when I’m less than a meter away from the router. Everything else on my house connects with no problem to my WiFi. Before migrating to Ubuntu the WiFi also worked with no problems. But since I installed Ubuntu my notebook won’t recognize the WiFi signal where I’ve always used my computer.

I had to change from Network Manager to WICD and now my notebook recognizes the wifi 1-2 meters away but still doesn’t work further than that.

Comment: It's hard to say what is wrong without more information. Please visit https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and review the accepted answer there, then return here and [edit] your post to include a link to the results of running the script. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 0):

Being so new, try installing aptitude. " apt-get install aptitude " Then run: " aptitude update " then " aptitude upgrade " This may improve the drives for you wifi device. Other than that, there is finding out its details and download the correct drivers. Personally, I bought a usb wifi device and it solved my issues as I could not find the correct driver to make the internal one work. I may simple be on its way out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could have the issue either with the driver or with the frequency transmission of the wifi.

1) If it's a driver problem, try to find the suitable one or update the old one.

2) If it's a frequency transmission problem, try to change the frequency by going to the advanced wifi settings and change it based on sub divisions as modern PC's have both 2.4 GHz variant as well as 5.2 GHz variant. By default it is configured in 2.4 GHz, so, change it to 5.2 GHz so that none of the other users will use the frequency and you will get the wifi at long distances if you use the wifi-a instead of wifi-b or wifi-ab.

When I had the problem, I checked the drivers and changed and configured all the frequency settings but the problem persisted. So, I got a wifi adaptor with a 5.2 GHz variant and it solved my problem and I know it is not the best way to solve the problem but I needed the problem to be sorted immediately. You can try all these and check it.

Hope this helps.